# ASP.default_aspx does not contain a definition for sButton_Click

Tags: c#

[image]

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Comment: What does the error message tell you?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is clear. You have added the event handler for the `Click`-event on aspx but you haven't provided it in codebehind:

```
protected void sbutton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // insert your code....
}
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere: sure, thanks

Comment: @HimBromBeere: i can read screenshots

Comment: @HimBromBeere read Line 57.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: he has registered an event handler on aspx but he hasn't provided it in codebehind.